# Passing argument containing space in shell script

Tags: shell

I need my script to be able to accept arguments with space characters. If, for example, I have a script as follows:

```
for SOME_VAR in $@
do
    echo "$SOME_VAR"
    cd "$SOME_VAR"
done;
```

If I pass arguments to the script (assuming it is called `foo.sh`)

```
sh foo.sh "Hello world"
```

I am expecting the script to print `Hello world` and change the directory to `Hello world`. But I get this error message instead:

```
hello
cd: 5: can't cd to hello
world
cd: 5: can't cd to world
```

How exactly do I pass an argument with a space character to a command in a shell script?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You must wrap the `$@` in quotes, too: `"$@"`

This tells the shell to ignore spaces in the arguments; it doesn't turn all arguments into a very long string.

Comment: XD thanks for the reply, I was like going to answer this myself, some further explanation http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#ARGLIST

Comment: But if $@ is a list putting " around it would basically merge it into one long string. It wouldn't iterate over it right?

And in that case there is no real use in having a for loop, a normal `echo "$@"; cd "$@"` would do.

Is there a solution where I can have `for i in `-constructs delimit on line break but not space?

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand: No. "$@" is a special token which means "wrap each individual argument in quotes". So `a "b c"` becomes (or rather stays) `"a" "b c"` instead of `"a b c"` or `"a" "b" "c"`.