# Calling commands in bash script with parameters which have embedded spaces (eg filenames)

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a bash script which does some processing on music files.  Here is the script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=printf"\n\0"

find `pwd` -iname "*.mp3" -o -iname "*.flac" | while read f
do
    echo "$f"
    $arr=($(f))
    exiftool "${arr[@]}"
done

IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

This fails with:

```
[johnd:/tmp/tunes] 2 $ ./test.sh 
./test.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `$(f)'
./test.sh: line 9: `    $arr=($(f))'
[johnd:/tmp/tunes] 2 $
```

I have tried many different incantations, none of which have worked.  The bottom line is I'm trying to call a command `exiftool`, and one of the parameters of that command is a filename which may contain spaces.  Above I'm trying to assign the filename `$f` to an array and pass that array to `exiftool`, but I'm having trouble with the construction of the array.

Immediate question is, how do I construct this array?  But the deeper question is how, from within a bash script, do I call an external command with parameters which may contain spaces?

Comment: answer for the space-in-the-arg problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905891/passing-argument-containing-space-in-shell-script (simply enclose "the spaced arg" into double quotes)

Comment: How about -exec exiftool {} ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually did have the call-with-possibly-space-containing-arguments syntax right (`program "${args[@]}"`). There were several problems, though.

Firstly, `$(foo)` *executes a command*. If you want a variable's value, use `$foo` or `${foo}`.

Secondly, if you want to append something onto an array, the syntax is `array+=(value)` (or, if that doesn't work, `array=("${array[@]}" value)`).

Thirdly, **please** separate filenames with `\0` **whenever possible**. Newlines are all well and good, but filenames can contain newlines.

Fourthly, `read` takes the switch `-d`, which can be used with an empty string `''` to specify `\0` as the delimiter. This eliminates the need to mess around with `IFS`.

Fifthly, be careful when piping into `while` loops - this causes the loop to be executed in a subshell, preventing variable assignments inside it from taking effect outside. There is a way to get around this, however - instead of piping (`command | while ... done`), use process substitution (`while ... done < <(command)`).

Sixthly, watch your process substitutions - there's no need to use `$(pwd)` as an argument to a command when `.` will do. (Or if you really must have full paths, try quoting the `pwd` call.)

### tl;dr

The script, revised:

```
while read -r -d '' f; do
    echo "$f" # For debugging?
    arr+=("$f")
done < <(find . -iname "*.mp3" -o -iname "*.flac" -print0)
exiftool "${arr[@]}"
```

### Another way

Leveraging `find`'s full capabilities:

```
find . -iname "*.mp3" -o -iname "*.flac" -exec exiftool {} +
# Much shorter!
```

## Edit 1

So you need to save the output of `exiftool`, manipulate it, then copy stuff? Try this:

```
while read -r -d '' f; do
    echo "$f" # For debugging?
    arr+=("$f")
done < <(find . -iname "*.mp3" -o -iname "*.flac" -print0)
# Warning: somewhat misleading syntax highlighting ahead
newfilename="$(exiftool "${arr[@]}")"
newfilename="$(manipulate "$newfilename")"
cp -- "$some_old_filename" "$newfilename"
```

You probably will need to change that last bit - I've never used `exiftool`, so I don't know precisely what you're after (or how to do it), but that should be a start.

Comment: This accomplishes what I set out above, so I'll accept.  Ultimately I need to do more than just call `exiftoo` though -- I need to save the return from `exiftool` to a variable, manipulate it with some logic to produce a filename, and then copy the original file to a new location using the new filename.  Can I use `exec` to do more than one thing, ie, more than just call `exiftool`?

Comment: @JohnDibling Sounds possible the long way (first script). I'll edit something in.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this just with bash:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
a=( **/*.{mp3,flac} )
exiftool "${a[@]}"
```

This probably works too: `exiftool **/*.{mp3,flac}`

Comment: Note that `globstar` requires `bash` 4. Some distributions may still have an earlier version.