# How to save terminal output of multiple files in UNIX?

Tags: java, linux, shell, unix

I have a java class file which I need to run on every file in a directory. I'm currently using the following command to run the program on every file in the directory

```
find . -type f -exec java JavaProgram {} \;
```

However instead of displaying the result in the terminal, I need it to output the result of each call to a separate file. Is there a command I could use that can recursively call a java program on a whole directory and save the terminal output of each call to a separate file?

Sort of like running `java JavaProgram inputfile > outputdir/outputfile` but recursively through every file in a directory where `'inputfile'` and `'outputfile'` have the same name.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
for i in $(find . -type f)
do
    java JavaProgram $i > ${i}.out
done
```

This will run the program against each file and write the output to `filename.out` in the same directory for each file. This approach is slightly more flexible than the one-line subshell approach in that you can do arbitrary transformation to generate the output filename, such as use `basename` to remove a suffix.

Comment: when I run the first line `for i in $(find . -type f)` I get the error Illegal Variable name. Does that have to do with the variable i?

Comment: Looping over the output from find like that will break on filenames with spaces or other whitespace characters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301039/how-can-i-escape-white-space-in-a-bash-loop-list

Comment: What OS and shell are you using? This syntax is for bash/ksh.  And, @ataylor is correct, this doesn't handle filenames with spaces. FOr that you should investigate `xargs`.

Comment: Im using Ubuntu Linux. And the files have no spaces.

Comment: @OliviaPanda that doesn't actually tell us what shell you're using; try `echo $SHELL` to get the answer.

Comment: output is /usr/local/bin/tcsh. Sorry I'm new to UNIX, is that the shell?

Answer (score 2):

Just exec a subshell to do the redirection.  For example:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c "java JavaProgram {} > outputdir/{}" \;
```