# Rename multiple files names with whitespace in terminal

Tags: terminal

I'd like to rename multiple files with a name such as this:

```
Screenshot at 2013-08-10 19:29:09.jpg
```

to:

```
0001.jpg
```

Or basically anything other then the original name which would be a little more convenient to work with.

I've tried the following script:

```
a=1
for i in *.jpg; do
  new=$(printf "%04d.jpg" ${a}) #04 pad to length of 4
  mv ${i} ${new}
  let a=a+1
done
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211595/renaming-files-in-a-folder-to-sequential-numbers).

But it gives me the following error, because of the spaces in the original file name.

```
mv: target `0021.jpg' is not a directory
```

If anyone could tell me the right way to get this done, I'd appreciate it.
Thank you!

Comment: have you tried with " around your variables? mv "${i}" ${new} e.g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inexperience on my part.. Found the solution in a different [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301039/how-can-i-escape-white-space-in-a-bash-loop-list).

The solution is to use `"$i"` instead of `$(i)`.

```
a=1
for i in *.jpg; do
  new=$(printf "%04d.jpg" ${a}) #04 pad to length of 4
  mv "$i" ${new}
  let a=a+1
done
```