# Move files from one folder structure to another

Tags: bash, file, ubuntu, terminal, directory

Let's say I have a directory structure like this:

```
/home/user/Desktop/test/testdir1/
/home/user/Desktop/test/testdir2/
/home/user/Desktop/test/testdir3/
```

and the same structure here:

```
/home/user/Documents/test/testdir1/
/home/user/Documents/test/testdir2/
/home/user/Documents/test/testdir3/
```

How can I move a file such as

```
/home/user/Desktop/test/testdir3/hello.txt
```

to the respective dir? (move only files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this command:

```
cd /home/user/Desktop/
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I'{}' echo mkdir -p '/home/user/Documents/{}'
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I'{}' echo mv '{}' '/home/user/Documents/{}'
```

Quoting the `{}` will ensure your script works with files containing spaces.

Also `-print0` and `-0` will pass your files from `find` to `xargs` using `\0` as a delimiter. This will ensure your script works with wierd filenames.

Remove the `echo` when if the script seems to be good for you. The use of `echo` is to test the command without the side effects.

Comment: Works nicely. Could you help me with one more thing? I need it to *copy* new directories from /home/user/Desktop/ to /home/user/Documents/ (and move the contents). Thanks.

Comment: execute this first: `find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I'{}' echo mkdir -p '/home/user/Documents/{}'`

Comment: Ah, I just noticed that will create folder with my file's names. (e.g. a folder name "test.txt")

Comment: the `-type d` part is very important it tells `find` to only output folder names, not file names

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /home/user/Desktop/
find . -type f -print | while read f; do mv "$f" "/home/user/Documents/$f"; done
```

In order to handle `spaces` in the file names, you should:

- Don't forget the `"` between source and targets.
- Use absolute path.

Please take a look at this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301039/how-can-i-escape-white-space-in-a-bash-loop-list), it is really helpful to handle `spaces` in file names.

Comment: @John1024, you're right. Already updated.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible solutions... Some better than others, depending on the details.

If the testdir directory structure is flat,

```
for orig in /home/user/Desktop/test/*
do
    targ=${orig/Desktop/Documents}
    mv -i $orig $targ
done
```

If nested, and the target directories don't necessarily exist (will be problems if files have spaces in the names), and assuming you don't want the nested directories moved:

```
for orig in $(find /home/user/Desktop/test/ -type f -print)
do
    targ=${orig/Desktop/Documents}
    targ_dir=$(dirname "$targ")
    [ ! -d "${targ_dir}" ] && mkdir -p "${targ_dir}"
    mv -i "$orig" "$targ"
done
```

Those are just examples (warning: not tested, only typed...)