# Looping through files defined by `*` in a variable in BASH

Tags: bash, loops

I want to be able to specify a directory with fastq files with a script that will loop through all the files and do some stuff. Here is my attempt:

```
threads=24
current_path=`pwd`
input_file=${current_path}/raw/

files=${current_path}/raw/*

for file in ${files}; do 

    output_file=${current_path}/${file}_out/
    mkdir -m gu=wrx,o=rx ${output_file}

    spades.py \
    --s1 ${input_file}${file} \
    -t ${threads} \
    --plasmid \
    --careful \
    -o ${output_file}

done
```

So in this script I get an error: `cannot make directory, directory does not exist` The script generates a `/home` folder. I don't know if I am specifying the files incorrectly or if I am using the for loop incorrectly.

Thank you!

Comment: For isolating the error, first write the for loop echoing the file name with v.gr. `echo about to process: "$file"`. If the current path contains spaces, you will probably identify an error because the file name will be split on two iterations of the loop.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301039/how-can-i-escape-white-space-in-a-bash-loop-list for looping over files with white space in the path.

Comment: Does `current_path` have spaces in it?

Comment: @oguzismail nope it is exactly like this `/home/user/lustre/article_5`

Comment: @roelofco : So maybe some entries in the `raw` directory have spaces?

Comment: @roelofco : _I get an error_ is a somewhat poor description of an error. Did you ever consider, that people will need to know, what kind of error you get?

Comment: It would be interesting to know the output of `pwd`. If it is `/home`, a common user is not allowed to create a directory there.

Comment: Look at the result of `echo "$output_file =>  mkdir -m gu=wrx,o=rx ${output_file}"`

Answer (score 0):

you concatenate full path to file with folder in line

```
output_file=${current_path}/${file}_out/
```

it should be

```
output_file=${file}_out/
```