# list --full-time with ls and a file list

Tags: grep, timestamp, ls

I gathered a list of zip in a remote disk using `find /path/ -name *.zip > ~/ziplist.txt`.

`~/ziplist.txt` look like this :

```
./path/to/the/file.zip
./path/to/the/file2.zip
./path/to/the/file3.zip
./path/to/the/very/nice/file.zip
```

I filtered this list using `grep` and now that I have to correct list in a `.txt` file, I would like to provide it to `ls x --full-time` to gather their timestamp (x being the list of files).

Is it possible ?

I tried something like this : `for f in tmp.txt do echo $( ls $f --full-time) done`

EDIT : anothier thing I tried is : `cat tmp.txt | sed- "s/\(.*\)/'\1'/" ; ls --full-time $(!!)`
The `sed` part is need since **obviously** there are space in file names...Otherwise, if files don't have spaces, this `$(!!)` works just fine.

A solution that could work I guess is also `ls -R --full-time | grep "what I want" > listfile.txt` but I think this will take a very long time to run. Having small steps is essential so I can check the list length for example, and because my disk access can be closed sometimes. Running `find` already took me one hour.

Note : I'm on windows10 and use git bash to run commands, so I can't run elaborate `.sh` scripts. I would prefer a single terminal entry to run it. I know, not the best configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed the content of a file directly into the command.

```
$: ls --full-time $(<~/ziplist.txt)
```

In this case, do NOT quote the file insertion, as that will treat the entire content of the file as a single filename.

To read them individually, [don't read lines with `for` loops](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

```
while read -r file; do ls --full-time "$file"; done < ~/ziplist.txt
```

Slower, but lets you quote the file names to avoid issues such as embedded spaces.

Before you spend too much time on that, please read why you should [not parse `ls` output](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

c.f. [stat](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html)

```
mapfile -t lst < ~/ziplist.txt && stat -c "%x %n" "${lst[@]}"
2021-06-18 13:44:18.351339200 -0500 dev
2021-10-21 20:50:20.649098700 -0500 sts
2021-10-21 09:11:37.398341900 -0500 file
2021-10-25 08:13:03.788650200 -0500 a b c
```

Note that `dev` is a directory here, and `a b c` has embedded spaces.
X, Y, and Z report access, modification, and status change, respectively, uppercase in seconds since the epoch, lowercase in human-parsed date/time with fractional seconds and timezone info.

Comment: I just edited the question, I achieve the same result using `$(!!)` after `cat ziplist.txt`. But now the issue is about space in file names. ^^'

Comment: stat is the very thing I need, thanks ! I don't think I have parse issue because all files have been created with windows and filenames are more restrictive. Just need to fix this space issue tho...

Comment: Windows allows spaces, and other things can get in that you wouldn't expect, but prefer `stat` or `find`. ;)

Comment: Accept the solution if it works for you? Always good policy!

Comment: It's not yet the solution ^^' I have spaces in my files. I'll accept it tho, but a little help to finish it would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Paul Hodges works fine if there is no spaces.
But this was my case so here are some informations.

First step, I find all zip files where they are and save their locations in a txt file:
`find /disk/Path/ -name *.zip > ~/ziplist.txt`

I then grep in this file to find those relative to my project using `grep`
`grep keyword ziplist.txt > mylist.txt`
I use `wc -l mylist.txt ; cat mylist.txt` to check this list.

Now I want to fond some time information about this file list. Since there is spaces in it, file path are broken. First I need to modify the internal field separator (IFS), with the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301039/how-can-i-escape-white-space-in-a-bash-loop-list) :

```
OLD_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
```

As I am on windows, the end of line (EOL) is not compatible with the new IFS. So I need to replace this with this [help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803162/how-to-change-windows-line-ending-to-unix-version).

```
dos2unix mylist.txt
```

Now I can use stat on the mylist.txt.

```
stat $(cat /Disk/Path/mylist.txt) --format %w%z > ~timefile.txt
```